# Missing files with Android Application Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package

When i create a new "Android Application Project" in Eclipse with the options "Create custom launcher icon", "Create activity" and "Create Activity" marked, it creates the project without the package "com.example.yourAppName" and without the folder "res/menu".

I want to know the reason and how i can solve this.

A few days ago, when i created a project with that options, it created all the default folders, but not now...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with the new Android SDK tools 22.6 update; it appears to have broken it. I just updated mine today and this happened. For some reason, they added a new 'create activity' checkbox on a second screen that was not on the previous version; this could be the cause of the error.

If you still have the original ZIP file like I did, the easiest solution is to remove eclipse and just extract the previous version. It'll then work again.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Android Application Project, you see Application Name, Project Name, Package name. What do you see in Package name?

P.S: I don't enough reputation to add it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clean` option menu to resulve this problem:
choose from menubar: `project`->`clean..` then

Answer (score 0):

always use some package pattern like com.orgname.yourpack motive. For your case please check the sdk version you use. Its happen most of the time bue to the newest version and you can rename any time your package by rightclick on project and then refactor.